# Add custom taxonomy to custom search for posts

Tags: php, wp-query

This is my code:

```
$data = wp_parse_args( $data, array(
    'post_type'     => array('post_type1','post_type2','post_type3'),
    'post_status'   => array('publish','closed')
) );

if ($data['s']){
    global $theme_query;
    $theme_query['s'] = explode(' ', $data['s']);
}

$query = new WP_Query($data);

return $query;
```

How can search for custom taxonomy with the custom post_types?
I don't have any idea what to do!

Answer (score 0):

you should go through all [wpQuery](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) docs for easily understand this. 
To do this task use this for for making query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_custom_postType',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your texonomy ', //like category, actor, people etc.
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'your_term', //like rock,bread, tom
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: You don't understand me, Your code is searched at the posts that have a taxonomy please read my question again I have my own ajax search and it's searching for posts only I want to be allowed to search taxonomies also.